# How to alter URL Parameters in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash, url, replace, parameters

I've got the following Problem:

I would like to alter the parameters of an URL. My idea was to first cut the parameters as a whole like that:

```
url="http://domain.com/file.php?par1=val1&par2=val2&par3=val3"
pars=$(cut -d"?" -f2 <<< $url)
```

So now

```
echo "$pars"
```

should give me a list of Parameters seperated by the "&" character.

```
par1=val1&par2=val2&par3=val3
```

I want to replace val1 with the variable $newpar then use curl to visit the website with the changed parameter. Then i want to change the parameter back to val1 and change val2 to $newpar and so on.
My question is: How do I do that?

I don't know how much parameters there will be, because the $url variable is read out of a file with URLs with a different number of parameters.
I think some kind of regex would come in handy and also that probably a for loop would do the trick. But I don't know exactly how.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `var1` is specific enough, the following should work:

```
url=${url/par1=val1/par1=$newpar}
```

The only problem would be if `par1` could be the suffix of another parameter, like

```
url="http://domain.com/file.php?par1=val1&otherpar1=val2&par3=val3"
```

In that case, use a regular expression to ensure `par1` is preceded by either `&` or `?`:

```
[[ $url =~ (.*)([?&])(par1=val1)(.*) ]]
url="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}par1=$newpar${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
```

Element 1 contains everything before the `?` or `&` that precedes the parameter you want to change. Element 2 contains the `?`/`&`. Element 2 is the text you want to replace; we use the replacement text instead of that element. Finally, element 3 contains the text, if any, that follows the parameter you are changing.

Comment: Thank you very much, but somehow if i echo it, it prints `"http://domain.com/file.phphttp://domain.com/file.phppar1=newparpar1=val1"`               Do you have an idea for my for loop? Btw my code for echoing $url is                       `newpar="newpar"
url="http://domain.com/file.php?par1=val1&par2=val2"
[[ $url =~ (.*)([?&])(par1=val1)(.*) ]]
url="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}par1=$newpar${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

echo "parameter $url"`            Did I make a mistake?

Comment: I used the wrong indices in several places; it should be correct now.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I'll try to figure out how to replace the par1 part with the next parameter. Maybe I'll save it to a temporary file separated with a new line and use a while loop with read. I'll try it later. But thanks a lot!